# Hex digest for Python's built-in hash function

Tags: python, hash, hexdump

I need to create an identifier token from a set of nested configuration values.
The token can be part of a URL, so – to make processing easier – it should contain only hexadecimal digits (or something similar).
The config values are nested tuples with elements of hashable types like `int`, `bool`, `str` etc.

My idea was to use the built-in `hash()` function, as this will continue to work even if the config structure changes.
This is my first attempt:

```
def token(config):
    h = hash(config)
    return '{:X}'.format(h)
```

This will produce tokens of variable length, but that doesn't matter.
What bothers me, though, is that the token might contain a leading minus sign, since the return value of `hash()` is a signed integer.

As a way to avoid the sign, I thought of the following work-around, which is adding a constant to the hash value.
This constant should be half the size of the range the value of `hash()` can take (which is platform-dependent, eg. different for 32-/64-bit systems):

```
HALF_HASH_RANGE = 2**(sys.hash_info.width-1)
```

Is this a sane and portable solution?
Or will I shoot myself in the foot with this?

I also saw suggestions for using `struct.pack()` (which returns a `bytes` object, on which one can call the `.hex()` method), but it also requires knowing the range of the hash value in advance (for the choice of the right format character).

**Addendum:**
Encryption strength or collisions by chance are not an issue.
The drawback of the `hashlib` library in this scenario is that it requires writing a converter that traverses the input structure and converts everything into a `bytes` representation, which is cumbersome.

Comment: I'd be inclined to do `mask = (1<<sys.hash_info.width) - 1` `h = hash(config) & mask`.

Comment: Ooh, clever. Might not be the mostest Pythonic-est ways of all...

Comment: Here's a demo of the principle using small integers: `[i & 0xf for i in range(-8, 8)]`. FWIW, this is a fairly standard Python idiom for converting signed integers to unsigned.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Well, you're proabably right – why would Python have bit-wise operators if you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Maybe you should add more info to your question. How important is it to avoid collisions? The built-in `hash` is very fast, and the built-in `dict` and `set` types use `hash`, but it's far less resistant to collisions than the cryptographic functions in `hashlib` which produce much larger hashes.

Comment: BTW, there's a [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) module for creating unique IDs. Yes, it requires bytes input, but that's easy enough to provide if your objects have decent `__repr__` methods: just encode the string returned by `repr()` to UTF-8.

Comment: Now that's a brilliant idea – of course, I can just call `repr()` on the whole structure for serialising! Why hadn't I thought of that...

Comment: As for Python's bitwise operators: `1<<n` is significantly faster than `2**n`, although many Python coders consider the latter to be more readable, unless you're already doing other bitwise stuff. And of course `1<<n` will raise `ValueError` if `n` is negative.

Comment: Are these hash values intended to be used beyond a single run of your program?  If so, you CANNOT use the built-in `hash()` - it's not guaranteed to be calculated the same way in all Python versions, and at some point string hashes started being intentionally being randomized on each program run.

Comment: Thanks, @jasonharper – they're not used across multiple runs. I knew somebody would bring it up, but I didn't want to put too much information into the post.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any of hash functions for getting unique string. Right now python support out of the box many algorithms, like: md5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, sha512. You can read more about it here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

This example shows how to use library hashlib. (Python 3)

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> sha = hashlib.sha256()
>>> sha.update('somestring'.encode())
>>> sha.hexdigest()
>>> '63f6fe797026d794e0dc3e2bd279aee19dd2f8db67488172a644bb68792a570c'
```

Also you can try library [hashids](https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python). But note that it's not a hash algorithm and you (and anyone who knows salt) can decrypt data.

```
$ pip install hashids
```

Basic usage:

```
>>> from hashids import Hashids
>>> hashids = Hashids()
>>> hashids.encode(123)
'Mj3'
>>> hashids.decode('Mj3')
123
```

Comment: Thanks – I'm aware of the `hashlib` module. What is inconvenient about it is that it only takes a flat `bytes` sequence as input. In my scenario this means traversing the config structure and converting each value to some `bytes` representation, which is cumbersome and error-prone.

Comment: That's right, but you can't use `hash` for some types like: list, dict, set, so you need to convert this structures as for `hashlib` module. You can check it manually `>>>hash({})`.

Comment: That's why I wrote in my post (first paragraph): “The config values are nested tuples with elements of hashable types like `int`, `bool`, `str` etc.” Note the word *hashable*.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create an identifier token from a set of nested configuration values

I came across this question while trying to solve the same problem, and realizing that some of the calls to `hash` return negative integers.

Here's how I would implement your `token` function:

```py
import sys


def token(config) -> str:
    """Generates a hex token that identifies a hashable config."""
    # `sign_mask` is used to make `hash` return unsigned values
    sign_mask = (1 << sys.hash_info.width) - 1
    # Get the hash as a positive hex value with consistent padding without '0x'
    return f'{hash(config) & sign_mask:#0{sys.hash_info.width//4}x}'[2:]
```

In my case I needed it to work with a broad range of inputs for the config. It did not need to be particularly performant (it was not on a hot path), and it was acceptable if it occasionally had collisions (more than what would normally be expected from `hash`). All it really needed to do is produce short (e.g. 16 chars long) consistent outputs for consistent inputs. So for my case I used the above function with a small modification to ensure the provided config is hashable, at the cost of increased collision risk and processing time:

```py
import sys


def token(config) -> str:
    """Generates a hex token that identifies a config."""
    # `sign_mask` is used to make `hash` return unsigned values
    sign_mask = (1 << sys.hash_info.width) - 1
    # Use `json.dumps` with `repr` to ensure the config is hashable
    json_config = json.dumps(config, default=repr)
    # Get the hash as a positive hex value with consistent padding without '0x'
    return f'{hash(json_config) & sign_mask:#0{sys.hash_info.width//4}x}'[2:]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd reccomend using hashlib

cast the token to a string, and then cast the hexdigest to a hex integer. Bellow is an example with the sha256 algorithm but you can use any hashing algorithm hashlib supports

```py
import hashlib as hl
def shasum(token):
    return int(hl.sha256(str(token).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16)
```